# How to delete an AMI using boto?

Tags: python, amazon-ec2, boto

(cross posted to [boto-users](https://groups.google.com/d/topic/boto-users/TSVqfgbAhRM/discussion))

Given an image ID, how can I delete it using boto?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You use the deregister() API.

There are a few ways of getting the image id (i.e. you can list all images and search their properties, etc)

Here is a code fragment which will delete one of your existing AMIs (assuming it's in the EU region)

```
connection = boto.ec2.connect_to_region('eu-west-1', \
                                    aws_access_key_id='yourkey', \
                                    aws_secret_access_key='yoursecret', \
                                    proxy=yourProxy, \
                                    proxy_port=yourProxyPort)


# This is a way of fetching the image object for an AMI, when you know the AMI id
# Since we specify a single image (using the AMI id) we get a list containing a single image
# You could add error checking and so forth ... but you get the idea
images = connection.get_all_images(image_ids=['ami-cf86xxxx'])
images[0].deregister()
```

(edit): and in fact having looked at the online documentation for 2.0, there is another way.

Having determined the image ID, you can use the deregister_image(image_id) method of boto.ec2.connection ... which amounts to the same thing I guess.

Comment: BTW, this with Boto 2.0b4, the latest. I didn't check to see if this works on earlier releases (latest Ubuntu repos for example has 1.9.something)

Answer (score 8):

With newer boto (Tested with 2.38.0), you can run:

```
ec2_conn = boto.ec2.connect_to_region('xx-xxxx-x')
ec2_conn.deregister_image('ami-xxxxxxx')
```

or

```
ec2_conn.deregister_image('ami-xxxxxxx', delete_snapshot=True)
```

The first will delete the AMI, the second will also delete the attached EBS snapshot

Comment: How to do the same usng Boto3? The problem is that you can't delete snapshot using deregister_image() function in Boto3 . What can be the other way around in Boto3?  http://boto3.readthedocs.org/en/latest/reference/services/ec2.html#EC2.Client.deregister_image

Comment: @tom Did you figure out a solution for this? Stuck in the same problem

Answer (score 6):

For Boto2, see [katriels answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11861452/783510). Here, I am assuming you are using Boto3.

If you have the AMI (an object of class `boto3.resources.factory.ec2.Image`), you can call its [`deregister`](https://boto3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/services/ec2.html#EC2.Image.deregister) function. For example, to delete an AMI with a given ID, you can use:

```
import boto3

ec2 = boto3.resource('ec2')

ami_id = 'ami-1b932174'
ami = list(ec2.images.filter(ImageIds=[ami_id]).all())[0]

ami.deregister(DryRun=True)
```

If you have the necessary permissions, you should see an `Request would have succeeded, but DryRun flag is set` exception. To get rid of the example, leave out `DryRun` and use:

```
ami.deregister() # WARNING: This will really delete the AMI
```

[This blog post](http://ranman.com/cleaning-up-aws-with-boto3/) elaborates on how to delete AMIs and snapshots with Boto3.

Answer (score 0):

Script delates the AMI and associated Snapshots with it. Make sure you have right privileges to run this script.

> Inputs - Please pass region and AMI ids(n) as inputs

```
import boto3
import sys

def main(region,images):
    region = sys.argv[1]
    images = sys.argv[2].split(',') 
    ec2 = boto3.client('ec2', region_name=region)
    snapshots = ec2.describe_snapshots(MaxResults=1000,OwnerIds=['self'])['Snapshots']
        # loop through list of image IDs
    for image in images:
        print("====================\nderegistering {image}\n====================".format(image=image))
        amiResponse = ec2.deregister_image(DryRun=True,ImageId=image)
        for snapshot in snapshots:
            if snapshot['Description'].find(image) > 0:
                snap = ec2.delete_snapshot(SnapshotId=snapshot['SnapshotId'],DryRun=True)
                print("Deleting snapshot {snapshot} \n".format(snapshot=snapshot['SnapshotId']))
    
main(region,images)
```

Answer (score 0):

using the EC2.Image resource you can simply call deregister():

Example:

```
for i in ec2res.images.filter(Owners=['self']):
    print("Name: {}\t Id: {}\tState: {}\n".format(i.name, i.id, i.state))
    i.deregister()
```

See this for using different filters:
[What are valid values documented for ec2.images.filter command?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47641237/what-are-valid-values-documented-for-ec2-images-filter-command/74524505#74524505)

See also: https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/ec2.html#EC2.Image.deregister