# What are valid values documented for ec2.images.filter command?

Tags: amazon-web-services, boto3

Noob question, where do I get information about valid tags for `ec2.images.filter` command? IE, it's not in Python API doc strings for `boto3`

```
import boto3
ec2 = boto3.resource('ec2', region_name='us-west-2')
image = list(ec2.images.filter(Filters=[{"Name":"Id", "Values": ["ami-405ade3a"]}]).all())[0]

ClientError: An error occurred (InvalidParameterValue) when calling the DescribeImages operation: The filter 'Id' is invalid
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They are documented in Boto3 EC2 images section.

See: [ec2.images.filter()](http://boto3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/services/ec2.html#EC2.ServiceResource.images)

Answer (score 0):

Available keywords to the images filter are:

ExecutableUsers, Filters, ImageIds, Owners, IncludeDeprecated and DryRun.

Request Syntax:

```
image_iterator = ec2.images.filter(
    ExecutableUsers=[
        'string',
    ],
    Filters=[
        {
            'Name': 'string',
            'Values': [
                'string',
            ]
        },
    ],
    ImageIds=[
        'string',
    ],
    Owners=[
        'string',
    ],
    IncludeDeprecated=True|False,
    DryRun=True|False
)
```

Here is an example using Owners:

```
for i in ec2res.images.filter(Owners=['self']):
    print("Name: {}\t Id: {}\tState: {}\n".format(i.name, i.id, i.state))
```

And here is an example using name:

```
for i in ec2res.images.filter(Filters=[{'Name': 'name', 'Values': ['My-Cool-Database-AMI']}]):
    print("Name: {}\t Id: {}\tState: {}\n".format(i.name, i.id, i.state))
```